# Moving files into folders

Tags: windows, file-management, directories

I have thousands of image files in a folder and I want a program to automatically create new folders and put fifty files in each folder.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a PowerShell job. Something like this should work:

```
# Create 100 folders
1..100 | % {New-Item -Name $_ -ItemType directory}

# select 50 files and move them into folder 1, 2, 3 etc until we hit 100
1..100 | % {
$files = ls | select -First 50
Move-Item $files .\$_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile C# code, I suggest using this program which takes a path (try `.`) and a number (`50`) as argument. It will create numeric subfolders and move files there. I release this code without warranty and co-licensed as CC-0.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace MoveNFilesToFolder
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var path = args[0];
                int n = int.Parse(args[1]);
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*");
                int fileno = 0;
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var subdir = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, "" + (fileno++/n)));
                    var targetfile = Path.Combine(subdir.FullName, Path.GetFileName(file));
                    try
                    {
                        File.Move(file, targetfile);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Could not move " + file + " to " + targetfile);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MoveNFilesToFolder <path> <count>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```